# hi i tried to import redux to react i put the order npm install redux

Tags: redux, installation, react-redux

i install npm redux also npm react-redux
did these code inside index .js

```
 import { createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
const reducer=(State={count:0} ,action)=>{
  return State;
}
const store= createStore(reducer)
root. Render(
  
    <Provider  >   
        <App />
    </Provider>
```

```
                             here
```

but it seem it doesn't read ***[createstore][1]***  because at the terminal i saw msg with install redux  make the location global
i changed in  4 file npm ,npm.exe ,xpn, xpn.exe and install redux and  react-redux again by these commands again  (npm i redux -global , npm i react-redux g   same thing
i locked at json it seems all file in json package.lock  is still same problem doesn't see create store i tried and i keep search it still same   any help please

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

consider adding store prop to the Provider component eg.:

```
    <Provider  store={store}>
```

To make your code cleaner, I recommend you to create your store in a separate file and export it there ..

Then in index.js, import the store and provide it to the Provider component as we did above